# Use EMAIL ACCOUNT registered with the device to send email, but without using intent

Tags: android, email

So far I'm working on an app that sends an email in the background after competing say, X task. I've accomplished it but with **hard-coded**(email id and password) through Java Mail Api.

I was wondering if there was a way, **I could use the default email account registered with device to send these emails**. Please read my question again and try to give me some solution!

*Note: I'm not using email intents and not planning to use them.*

Comment: What is "the default email account registered with device"?

Comment: The gmail account user has registered in his device to access app store. I guess this is the same account ACTION_SEND intent uses to send email.

Comment: I trying to do the same thing as the ACTION_INTENT does, but with having the user to click the 'SEND' button. Just send an email in the background using the devices gmail account

Comment: Please understand that only some of the billion Android device users use Gmail.

Comment: I understand I just gave an example of the account. That is the main reason why I would like to send email via devices account.